# What is a connex relation?.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields

I've been recently trying to teach myself some topology and in  the book I'm reading there is the definition of an order relation which confuses me a lot
.
[image]

I've looked online for more information and they seem to define an order relation differently namely one that is transitive,antisymmetric and reflexive.

So why does the author define it in this way my 2nd confusion has to do with what comparability actually means as there is actually no definition online and I cant quite understand what a connex relation is either and that seems to come up a lot in the definition of an order relation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compare... $<$ and $\leq$.  These are prototypical examples of orders.  The first is a *strict* order and requires nonreflexivity.  The second is reflexive.  It is true that there is no $x$ such that $x<x$ in the real numbers.  It is true that for every $x$ we have $x\leq x$ in the real numbers.

Comment: As for comparability... again, look at examples which are or aren't.  We have for every real numbers $x,y$ we either have $x<y$ or $y<x$ or $x=y$.  Now, compare to $\subset$ for sets.  We might have sets $X,Y$ such that none of $X\subset Y,~Y\subset X,~X=Y$ are true, for example $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1,3\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz is comparability the same  as aconnex relation then?

Comment: **a**connex sounds like *not* connex.  I fear you have words mixed up.  I use the word "*total*" instead usually.  From what I see, *connex* means that a relation $\preceq$ is "*connex*" iff for every $x,y$ we have $x\preceq y$ or $y\preceq x$.  On the other hand "*semiconnex*" for iff for every $x,y$ we have $x\prec y$ or $y\prec x$ or $x=y$.

Comment: @JMoravitz in the definition of connex why is the third condition or $x=y$ does that imply a connex relation cannot be reflexive. That is if $x \leq y$ are related in the connex relation can they not be equal?

Comment: A connex relation is reflexive.  It is a semiconnex relation which is nonreflexive.  Again, look at the examples of $<$ (*which is semiconnex*) and $\leq$ (*which is connex*).

Comment: @JMoravitz ok so a semiconnex relation cannot be reflexive but in the definition they use or which is inclusive right so all 3 statements could hold which would make it reflexive.

Comment: ... the pictured definition is of a connex relation which is an order... what I would normally call a "*strict total order.*" Notice property (2) they required nonreflexivity.  You cannot have a relation simultaneously be nonreflexive and reflexive, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditonally, we first define a partial order (sometimes even a preorder before that) to be reflexive, antisymmmetric ($xRy$ and $yRx$ implies $x=y$, this a pre-order need not be) and transitive. Lots of examples of this: order on $\Bbb Q$ adn $\Bbb Z$, inclusion relations etc. etc.

Then among those we single out linear orders (the orders we grow up with on "numbers" are mostly linear): we want comparability: $x=y$ or otherwise $xRy$ or $yRx$ must hold (not both as this would imply $x=y$ again). But then peope wanted to axiomatise $x < y$ instead of $x \le y$ and the distinguishing things there are: no reflexivity (never $x< x$ so $xRx$ is always forbidden) and asymmetry: if $xRy$ then never $yRx$), so the relation always has to decide on one of them.

A [connex relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connex_relation) is sort of a generalisation of the linear order: we always want either $xRy$ or $yRx$. We then don't demand transivity or asymmetry or antisymmetry necessarily. So it can be a very different thing. E.g. After a round-robin tournament in a game without draws, the players will have constructed a connex relation at the end ($xRy$ : $x$ has beaten $y$), which is the also nonreflexive as you cannot beat yourself.

Linear orders I can see the importance of, and they have a rich theory (order types etc) but connex relations don't add much in my opinion. I've never seen them in any of the papers I studied.

Comment: thanks a lot as usual for the great explanations it has cleared my confusion.

Comment: @Thehomeschooler glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The book you’re reading is not helping yourself. It defines an order relation to be a linear order relation, which is really unusual and not good.

Then an order can be strict or not. Wikipedia [order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory?wprov=sfti1) presents order relations in a more *standard way*.

Comment: sorry but what exactly is the book I'm using defining then?

Comment: The first sentence of **Order relations** paragraph identifies an order relation with a linear order. This is not at all usual to impose comparability axiom for an order relation. Only for a linear order.

Comment: Downvoter,  a comment will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "really unusual and not good" is far from my experiences. I've often seen "order" used to mean "linear order".

Comment: @AndreasBlass You’re right that this may be strong. At least, in mathematical logic (model theory), I rarely saw orders confused with linear orders.